# Puppeteer Uncatchable Target Closed Error

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I am having problems with using puppeteer.
Every 10 to 50 requests I get the following error:

```
TargetCloseError: Protocol error (Network.getCookies): Target closed
at CallbackRegistry.clear (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:153:36)
at CDPSessionImpl._onClosed (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:468:70)
at Connection.onMessage (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:265:25)
at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/NodeWebSocketTransport.js:62:32)
at callListener (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:290:14)
at WebSocket.onMessage (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:209:9)
at WebSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1184:20)
at Receiver.emit (node:events:513:28)
at Receiver.dataMessage (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:541:14)
at Receiver.getData (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:459:17)
at Receiver.startLoop (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:158:22)
at Receiver._write (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:84:10)
at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
```

And the biggest problem with it is the fact that it is not catchable and therefore causes my whole app to crash.

I use `await` before **every** puppeteer-action and here is all of my code that involves puppeteer:

```
let browser = null;
try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: "new",
        args: [
            `--user-agent=${userAgent}`,
            '--no-sandbox'
        ]
    });
    browser.on('disconnected', () => browserDisconnected = true)
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await useProxy(page, proxyUrl);
    await page.goto(url);
    await setTimeout(pageLoadTimeout);
    await page.waitForSelector("#Title");

    const renderedContent = await page.content();
    const $ = cheerio.load(renderedContent);

    const title = $("#Title").html();

    output = { title: title };
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    output =  { error: true, error: error.message };
} finally {
    try {
        if(browser !== null) {
            await browser.close();
        }
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("ERROR CLOSING BROWSER:");
        console.log(error);
    }
    return output;
}
```

I've stripped the code from any tasks that don't involve puppeteer.

I am absolutely clueless on how to handle this error and I've pretty much seen any SO, Github, ... issue on this topic.
It would already be helpful if I could catch the error so it doesn't cause my whole server to crash and have to restart.

Where am I running the server?
In a docker container with the following platform `--platform=linux/amd64 node:18` in Google App Engine.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: hm, puppeteer does not send cookies the Network.getCookies command unless you call the cookies getter on the page. Is there any other code that calls it?

Comment: Nope, there's nothing that involves a cookie getter being called.
Edit: There used to be but I removed it at some point, which shouldn't have any influence on it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a hint in the right direction by @Yaroslavm, I've now found the cause and solution for this particular problem.

The issue was with `await useProxy(page, proxyUrl);` from the `puppeteer-page-proxy'`package. The error occurred internally within the package.

Luckily there is another way to use a proxy with Puppeteer.

I've found the following solution (https://pixeljets.com/blog/how-to-set-proxy-in-puppeteer/):

```
const oldProxyUrl = `http://${proxy.username}:${proxy.password}@${proxy.address}:${proxy.port}`;
 const newProxyUrl = await proxyChain.anonymizeProxy(oldProxyUrl);

browser = await puppeteer.launch({
   headless: "true",
   args: [
     `--user-agent=${userAgent}`,
     '--no-sandbox',
     `--proxy-server=${newProxyUrl}`
   ]
});

const page = await browser.newPage();
```

Done!

The link I provided above mentions more options which I have yet to test.
I hope I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Puppeteer usually acts same way, when file execution was finished, but there are still some actions that are not properly awaited (in Promise pending status).

Are this functions async?

> const $ = cheerio.load(renderedContent);
>
> const title = $("#Title").html();

If yes - try to await for them to be resolved.

Comment: These functions aren't async. Every action that is async is awaited.

Comment: Can you provide code of useProxy and setTimeout?

Also, I suggest to use     await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

I had a case when getting element from not rendered page caused it's crash.

Comment: I'v e removed the setTimeout function yet the problem persists.
You can find useProxy here: https://github.com/Cuadrix/puppeteer-page-proxy

Comment: I think, it fails somewhere there https://github.com/Cuadrix/puppeteer-page-proxy/blob/master/src/core/proxy.js#L15
Try to set small timeout between opening page and setting up proxy and to see if it helped.

Comment: Wow, great clue - thanks!
I'll give it a try and inform you if it resolved the issue.

Comment: This did sadly not resolve the error